# Обрамить текст в html тэги

Tags: python-3.x

Используя BeautifulSoup, я достаю с сайта набор данных (текст):

```
text = text.find('div', class_='catalog').text.strip()
```

На выходе получается список:

```
Данные 1
Данные 2
Данные 3
```

Нужно этот список обрамить в тэг `<p>`. Чтобы на выходе получалось:

```
<p>Данные 1</p>
<p>Данные 2</p>
<p>Данные 3</p>
```

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи f-строк (require python >= 3.6 ):

```
l = ['Данные 1', 'Данные 2', 'Данные 3']
print([f"<p>{i}</p>" for i in l])
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Ваш пример также обрамляет все символы в <p></p>, а нужно строку до переноса

Comment: Не понимаю о чём Вы, но подозреваю, что у Вас просто не "список" (как Вы сказали) на выходе, а `str`. Полагаю сначала это надо привести действительно к _списку_ и потом уже выполнять рекомендации из ответов.

Comment: Вы правы, привел к списку, все работает! Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
l = ['Данные 1',
     'Данные 2',
     'Данные 3']
l = list(map(lambda x: '<p>{}</p>'.format(x), l))
```

Comment: Здравствуйте! Попробовал ваш пример, наверное я делаю что-то неправильно, но у меня каждый символ обрамился в <p></p>: `text = list(map(lambda x: '<p>{}</p>'.format(x), text))`

Comment: @l.Z. так вы в вопросе сказали что у вас получился список, а получается у вас строка. Преобразуйте ее в список  text.split( '\n')

Comment: Да, Вы абсолютно правы, Ваш пример тоже работает. Это я некорректно задал вопрос (извиняюсь). Спасибо!